# Change IIS Express Configuration/Metabase location

Tags: visual-studio-2015, iis-express

Is there some way to change the IIS Metabase location from

%userprofile%\documents\iisexpress\config\applicationhost.config

to another folder?

My problem is in my company this directory is on a remote file server. Sometimes this server is unavailable, which makes it impossible to run any application using local IIS and VS 2015.

TKS.

Comment: I'm looking for this answer as well, but in the meantime, if you have admin rights, you can open regedit and go to HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders and change the "Personal" key to what you need. You can export this registry setting and double click the file whenever you need to reapply it.